# Kubuntu launch menu no longer takes keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, kde, 20.10

Ever since I updated to 20.10 I can no longer search for applications in the KDE launch menu.  The keyboard works fine for anything else and no amount of clicking on the search bar makes it take input.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  Please see "[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)" and [KDE's Bugtracking System](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a KDE bug. You should maybe refer to the [KDE forum](https://forum.kde.org/) for this type of stuff.